# HashMap defined using groovy syntax not working with Character Keys

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Does groovy not have matured support for generics? If I am explicitly saying I want a Map<Character, Character> will it not respect it?

The below code fails because map.get(Character) is giving me null. When I use Map<String, String> it works.

```
String eq = "{([])}"
Map<Character, Character> map =   [ '}':'{', ')': '(', ']': '[' ]
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack();
Character[] arr = eq.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Character c = arr[i]
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
        stack.push(c)
    } else { // check for the end
        char c1 = stack.peek()
        **// map.get(c) is null here**
        if (c1 == map.get(c)){ 
            stack.pop()
        } else {
            stack.push(c)
        }
    }
}

if (stack.isEmpty()) {
    println "Balanced Eq"
} else {
    println "Not Balanced Eq"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy uses `'` for *string* literals and *not* for chars (like Java).  `"`-literals allow `${}` replacements, `'`-literals don't.

If you want those error catched, you most likely want to add `TypeChecked` or `CompileStatic` as compiler option or as annotations on the places, that depend on it.  The default, "dynamic" Groovy does not care much for generics.